# How to expand panel when clicking ONLY on text and NOT on the entire header panel?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a simple accordion, and in order to **expand/collapse** each panel I would like to **ONLY** click on the **header text** from each panel and **NOT** on the whole panel header. Does anyone know how to make this happen?.

For example, if I click on **Header 1** text I want the panel to **expand/collapse**
Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/S7AEAPYh1R6QxNyrRU69?p=preview)

```
<p-accordion>
 <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
   Content 1
 </p-accordionTab>
 <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
    Content 2
 </p-accordionTab>
 <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
    Content 3    
 </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is using custom template `p-header` from primeng `SharedModule`:

```html
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab>
       <p-header>Header 1</p-header>
       Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab>
       <p-header>Header 2</p-header>
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab>
        <p-header>Header 3</p-header>
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

and now you need to add some rules to your global css file:

```css
.ui-accordion-header {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ui-accordion-header p-header {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[**Forked Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eqkqlGRWM6YGDUzm2omt?p=preview)

Comment: What if I also want to alert a message when clicking on the Header text? I mean, is it possible to create a function that will get fire when clicking on the header text?. Example: call function myFunction() that will execute alert('testing')

Comment: Updated plunker

Comment: @yurzuu Is it possible to add a button on header panel 1 ( Example: myButton) so that when you click on it it calls myFunction2 and executes a message like: alert('testing button') ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated plunker. You can check it. But seems it is not related to your initial question and angular